# How to avoid Quick Look Simulator from launching on every run?

Tags: xcode, macos, simulator, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller

I am trying to debug my Quick Look Extension target (Preview) for **macOS** in *Xcode* and, although I have specified a different executable (`qlmanage`), it keeps launching the *Quick Look Simulator* every time I run it in *Xcode* which is annoying.

How can I stop the *Quick Look Simulator*from launching along with my `qlmanage` preview? I don't see a way of disabling this in my Scheme.

Thanks.

[image]